# Game built with Libgdx RoboVM will not play sound on iPad

Tags: ipad, audio, libgdx, robovm

I have created a very simple game using Libgdx. There are some buttons on the scree, when the uses presses a button a specific sound file plays.

I initialize my sound like this:

```
Sound mysound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("sounds/mysoundfile.mp3"));
```

and I play it like this:

```
mysound.play();
```

Everything works perfectly on Windows Desktop, Mac Desktop (El Capitan), and Android (tested on Galaxy Tab 10.1, and a Sony Z3), and on my iPod Touch.

However when I run the game on an iPad Air (MD785LLB), the sounds won't play. Volume is turned up, and I can play other music and sounds on the device (outside of the game) and it works fine. But the game will not make any sound. There are no error messages being logged but nothing plays out of the speaker.

Originally my sound files were mp3, but I have tried converting to wav as well and that did not change the behavior, still plays no sound.

**EDIT:** The game does run correctly and plays sound on both the iPad Air, and iPad Air 2 Simulators. The simulators are listed at version 9.2.

Comment: Does it work with the simulator of the same device? What iOS version are you using? It seems there is either an OS problem or device problem (which can have to do with some settings like in the plist file).

Comment: Once I didn't get any sound from the iPhone because it was disabled with the stupid side button... :D

Comment: OP says he hears other sounds on the device so this should not be the problem

Comment: @p.streef I don't know the version for sure, I think it was 8.4 but I'll have to check later today. I haven't had a chance to test with simulator yet. I'll give a try today. And I know the sound is enabled because I can play other songs and files outside of the game and hear them.

Comment: Are you using the exact same build? Or are you rebuilding for all different devices (for iOS i mean)? Have you tried a clean and rebuild? Have you tried to rebuild for a different device and is the sound there again? If all those answers are yes. This is a strange problem. If one of them is no, do that first and then try again! Clearing cache/rebuilding can actually solve some problems for roboVM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out iPads have a hardware switch on the side of them near the volume buttons. This switch acts as some kind of mute, and a screen rotation lock.

Libgdx / RoboVM and probably other types of games seem to be affected by the mute functionality of this switch. But some other types of sounds are not, like playing an audio file, and html5 `<audio>` tag on a page in safari both of these still work no matter what position the switch is in.

I moved the switch until there was no orange color showing and then the game was able to play sounds successfully.